# Access multidimensional array with Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js

How can I access properties in objects inside multidimensional arrays using v-for with VueJS?

```
var arr =[{"fruit": {"fruitName": "apple"}, "vegetable":[{"vegetableName": "carrot" }]}];
```

Trying to print it like:

```
  <ul v-for="x in arr">
    <li>{{ x.fruit.fruitName }}</li>
    <li>{{ x.vegetable.vegetableName }}</li>
  </ul>
```

Can only print the fruitname, can't access the property in the array inside the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `0` index to get value since it's property of nested object inside an array.

```
<li>{{ x.vegetable[0].vegetableName }}</li>
<!--            --^^^--                 -->
```